# How to create a new column with how many times a value in another variable repeats in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a new column in a dataframe in which I can count how many times a value in another variables. I want my outcome to be like the column "count"

| Product | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | 3 |
| orange | 2 |
| Apple | 3 |
| orange | 2 |
| Apple | 3 |
| Pear | 1 |

I have tried the following:

df['Prodct'].value_counts()

Hence, I have the list of the count for each product, but I don't know how to put it in the data frame how I stated before

Comment: `df['Count'] = df['Product'].value_counts()`?

Comment: Not exactly, but I haver already manage to solve. It was: df.assign(**{'count': lambda df: df.groupby('product')['product'].transform('count')}) Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to achieve?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

fruits = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana', 'Kiwi', 'Mango']

# bootstrap fruits
samples = np.random.choice(fruits, size=100, replace=True)

df = pd.DataFrame({'fruit': samples})

print(df.head())

count_dict = df['fruit'].value_counts().to_dict()
df['count'] = df['fruit'].map(count_dict)

print('-------------')

print(df.head())
```

The code above yields the following output:

Before the modification:

```
    fruit
0    Kiwi
1  Orange
2  Banana
3  Orange
4   Apple
```

After the modification:

```
    fruit  count
0    Kiwi     28
1  Orange     20
2  Banana     19
3  Orange     20
4   Apple     18
```

Comment: Not exactly, but I haver already manage to solve.

It was:

df.assign(**{'count': lambda df: df.groupby('product')['product'].transform('count')})

Thanks anyways